# why android receive data is byte -32 via ble bt-410

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm try to send and receive data between Android device and Arduino Mega 2560 via bluetooth low energy bt-410,
When I receive data type is byte[] and I decode to string it's a question symbol so I try to Log byte[] convert to byte and then value is -32, and when I send some string from my app to Serial Monitor in Arduino is nothing.
how can I send and receive data?

```
//Receive data:
@Override
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt mGatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(mGatt, characteristic);

        String textRX;
        try {
             textRX = new String(characteristic.getValue(), "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writeLine("Received: " + textRX);
        hideKeyboard();
        scrollDown();
}

//Send data:
public void sendClick(View view) {
        String message = editInput.getText().toString();
        if (tx == null || message.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            value = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tx.setValue(value);
        if (mGatt.writeCharacteristic(tx)) {
            writeLine("Sent: " + message);
            editInput.setText("");
            hideKeyboard();
            scrollDown();
            Log.e("textTX", tx + "");
        } else {
            writeLine("Couldn't write TX characteristic!");
        }
}

//Arduino Code:
String inputString="";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial.available() > 0) {
    inputString = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    Serial.println(inputString);
    if (inputString == "R1") {
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("R1 on");
    }
  }
  delay(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bytes in Java are signed, not the *most* bone-headed decision I've ever seen but it comes close. There are possibly use cases where it makes sense to treat it as signed, but I can't think of any off the type of my head. I probably would have preferred an unsigned `byte` type, using a type like `shorter` as the signed variant :-)

In any case, that means that getting a value greater than `127` from your comms channel is going to look like a negative number to Java.

More precisely, it will look like `unsignedEquivalent - 256` and that should therefore provide you the clue on how to "fix" it.

Take your byte, put it into a wider data type (such as `int`), then add `256`:

```
byte bdata = -32;   // should have been 224
int idata = bdata;
idata + 256;        // is 224
```